# How to store multiple rows in single button click using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In the database I created a stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usercusdet_pro](@user varchar(25),@cusname varchar(max))--,@cnt int)
as
begin
    --declare @count int
    --set @count=0
    --if(@count<@cnt)
    insert usercusdet values(@user,@cusname)
end
```

to insert values. When I click the button, multiple rows should be inserted in the table.

```
int cnt = gvTranferRows.Rows.Count;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gdb"].ConnectionString);

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usercusdet_pro", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    con.Open();

for (int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "A001";
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusname",gvTranferRows.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
     //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnt", cnt);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I try to add value it shows an error:

> procedure or function has too many arguments specified

What's the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the parameters before the next iteration i.e.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "A001";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusname",gvTranferRows.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnt", cnt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

Or given the `@user` parameter is fixed, you just need to replace the `@cusname` one

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "A001";
for (int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusname",gvTranferRows.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt("@cusname");
}
```

Comment: hai james it worked.thanks.one more doubt where insert into table it stored in the random order. it is not inserting one by one like as ususal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Table valued parameter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters) starting sql server 2008 onwards.

OR

Youc an go for [passing data as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600091/how-to-pass-xml-from-c-sharp-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008) if using version prior to SQL Server 2008.

OR

Not a good apporach but you can use delimiter seperated string as well.