# How to pass multiple parameters into a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on ASP.NET web application. In that I have one Edit Information page which has around 40 text-boxes. I need to update the data in the database, so I need to pass the values from all 40 fields into the database.

I am passing 40 parameters to a stored procedure to update data in the database. I need some other way to pass these parameters. Please suggest how to pass multiple parameters to a stored procedure.

Is there any other way to pass data or is it only possible, writing all in parameters list?

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What is the problem with adding 40 parameters? 40 lines of code is really not that bad, if you are feeling particularly lazy you can use the `sys.parameters` system table to make writing the code quicker: `SELECT 'command.Parameters.AddWithValue("' + Name + '", ' + STUFF(Name, 1, 1, '') + 'TextBox.Text);' FROM sys.parameters WHERE Object_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourProcedureName');`

Answer (score 1):

Forty parameters should not be a showstopper, but if you really want to pass fewer arguments to a stored procedure, you could consider [passing an XML argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3600091/1810429) that encapsulates the 40 values to the stored procedure - for example...

```
<booksdetail> 
  <isbn_13>800007890</isbn_13> 
  <isbn_10>07890B</isbn_10> 
  <image_url>http://www.whatever.com/Books/large/00/800007890.jpg</image_url> 
  <title>Some Title</title> 
  <description>The incredible story of....</description>
  -- ...
</booksdetail>
```

...passed to `@bookDetail xml` instead of the values therein passed to:

```
@isbn_13 varchar(13),
@isbn_10 varchar(10),
@image_url varchar(100),
@title varchar(100),
@description varchar(250),
-- ...
```

You would still have to account for the 40 values in the stored procedure, but if your preference is a slimmer stored-proc signature, this approach will achieve as much.