# Pass XML to a stored procedure in node

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out how to pass an XML value to a stored procedure using [MSSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) node driver, from the documentation I can see that the driver does support stored procedures, and you also define custom data types like this:

```
sql.map.register(MyClass, sql.Text);
```

but I haven't found an example how can it be done for XML so far.

I did find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3600742/1729349) but for a .NET SQL driver, trying to figure out if anyone has done this for Node.

**UPDATE**

I was able to send an XML to a stored procedure and parse it in DB, here's the example:

```
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
var xml = '<root><stock><id>3</id><name>Test3</name><ask>91011</ask></stock></root>'
request.input('XStock', sql.Xml, xml);

request.execute('StockUpdateTest', function (err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know this special case, but there are some general ideas:

The input parameter of a stored procedure, which should take some XML, can be either `XML`, `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. Well, just to mention this, `VARBINARY` might work too, but why should one do this...

A string in SQL-Server is either 8-bit encoded (`VARCHAR`) or 16-bit (`NVARCHAR`), **XML is - in any case - `NVARCHAR` internally**.

Most cases will be casted implicitly. You can pass a valid XML as `VARCHAR` or as `NVARCHAR` and assign this to a variable of type `XML`. Both will work. But you will get into troubles if your XML includes special characters...

**Important**: If the XML includes a declaration like `<?xml ... encoding="utf-8"?>` it **must** be handed over to the XML variable as `VARCHAR`, while `utf-16` **must** be `NVARCHAR`. This declaration would be omitted in SQL Server in any case, so easiest is, to pass the XML as string without such a declaration.

The clear advise is, to **pass an XML as 16-bit unicode string without `<?xml ...?>`-declaration**. Doing so, there will be no implicit casting and you will not run in troubles with special characters and/or encoding issues.

Your SP can either define the parameter as `XML` or as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and assign it to a typed variable internally.

Hope this helps!