# Insert single xml element into sql like string manipulation

Tags: asp.net, sql, xml

Hi I have a XML file like this

```
<pictures>
<mainimg>
<link>http://s.freshnewtracks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dr_dre_20011.jpeg</link>
</mainimg>
<img>
<title>back</title>
<link>http://s.freshnewtracks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dr_dre_20011.jpeg</link>
</img>
<web></web>
<twitter></twitter>
<facebook></facebook>
<myspace></myspace>
<about></about>
</pictures>
```

I need to INSERT this XML into a SQL Datatable without using XML file on disk. I have seen other examples where it is done by using a xml file on disk. I want to do this with typed/string XML without saving to disk/BULK [Link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server.aspx&ei=i0mbUffAB_SY0AWTtoDIAg&usg=AFQjCNHIycw6hRuG6a80Ur_ekojWxnKefQ&sig2=3vTNOLGdYVB_83AXrEUKVw&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k) For eg something like

```
INSERT INTO Table (XMLColumn)
VALUES (XML LIKE STRING)
```

Is this possible? Can I have some controls over the elements of XML file for each row?

Comment: You should be able to use parameterised SQL using the SqlDbType.Xml parameter type. Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557882/stored-procedure-pass-xml-as-an-argument-and-insert-key-value-pairs/3558102#3558102 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600091/how-to-pass-xml-from-c-sharp-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass this XML as string to stored procedure
 and get this xml string by @XML XML  = null in the stored procedure

In the SP:

```
insert into Table(column_name) 
                                      SELECT 
         @Applicationo_new
            ,column_name  = t.p.value('column_name', 'varchar(20)') 
    FROM @XML.nodes('pictures') t(p);
```